# Render multiple controls in the same line in Jade (express)?

Tags: pug

How would I render multiple controls in the same line in Jade (express)? Eventually I want to achieve something as depicted in the image below [image]

```
| Login
br
br
| Username 
input#username(type='text', value='')
| Password
input#username(type='password', value='')           
br
br
input#btnSignin(type='button', value='Login')
hr
```

Thanks,
M

Comment: you can accomplish this in client-side CSS there is no need for `<br/>` tags here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your example has not necessary something to do with *Node.js*, *Express* or *Jade*, but here is a quick fix for your Problem, but a lot nicer is what [@Phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333329/phoenix) said in his comment above. I just don't want to write this 'code' too, I'm sure you can do that on your own.

First your example will create something like that in *HTML*:

```
Login<br/><br/>Username 
<input id="username" type="text" value=""/>Password
<input id="username" type="password" value=""/><br/><br/>
<input id="btnSignin" type="button" value="Login"/>
<hr/>
```

Thats not what you wanted, but here is a quick and dirty version in *Jade*, that looks more like your given example (your picture):

```
| Login
br
br
div(style="float: left;") Username
  br
  input#username(type='text', value='')
div(style="float: left;") Password
  br
  input#username(type='password', value='')
div(style="float: left;")
  br
  input#btnSignin(type='button', value='Login')
br
br
hr
```

This will end up in following *HTML*:

```
Login<br/><br/>
<div style="float: left;">Username<br/>
  <input id="username" type="text" value=""/>
</div>
<div style="float: left;">Password<br/>
  <input id="username" type="password" value=""/>
</div>
<div style="float: left;"><br/>
  <input id="btnSignin" type="button" value="Login"/>
</div><br/><br/>
<hr/>
```

Finally: Here is a [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bEN7p/) with both versions.

Comment: Hi Ztirom, I am new to Jade and was trying to figure out if it can be achieved inherently using Jade syntax without applying css. Looks like only option is css. I know its not related to Node and express but wanted more hits on the Q. I will remove node and express tag.... I will leave Jade as many of the developers new to Jade might have similar query and this might help them. Thanks for your answer. appreciate it.